# Is there a C# equivalent to Java's BlockingQueue.drainTo(Collection) method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I am building a multithreaded C# application in which multiple threads contribute to elements on a queue. A single thread is consuming the elements on that same queue. I would like the single thread to do some reduction/merging of elements of the incoming elements, so ideally it would look at all new elements on the queue, reduce them and then process the entries after reduction. A bit like this:

```
while (true)
{
  Collection<Elem> elements = queue.TakeAll();
  Collection<Elem> reducedElements = Reduce(elements);
  for (Elem e in reducedElements)
  {
    process(e);
  }
}
```

But there obviously isn't any TakeAll() method. From Java experience I am used to the [BlockingQueue's drainTo method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo(java.util.Collection)) which offers something like what I'm interested in.

I could implement something myself by just using TryTake until the queue is empty. But that has the risk that the producing threads may potentially be busy producing also and that would cause there to be no finite ending of the collection to reduce and process. I'm basically looking for a way to take everything out of the queue, leaving it empty but providing a collection that can be worked on.

Comment: Good api design is not knowing what to add, it is knowing what *not* to include. A TryDrainTo() and "the behavior of this operation is undefined ..." surely made it land on the cut list very early.  Thread-safety was a primary design goal in the .NET flavor, don't overlook that when you add your own (extension) method.

Comment: Well, then it could probably provide a similar method a la TryTakeAll() or something like that. Right now it seems I don't have a way to atomically take out all elements that are in the queue at a particular point in time. The moment I start taking out elements, more elements may be added by producers at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `ConcurrentQueue` in namespace System.Collections.Concurrent.

This Queue is made for thread safe operations.

You can easy add an extension methode for your purpose.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> DrainTo<T>(this System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> poConcurrentQueue)
    {
        List<T> loList = new List<T>();
        T loElement;
        while (poConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out loElement))
            loList.Add(loElement);
        return loList;
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<string> loConcurrentQueue = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<string>();

loConcurrentQueue.Enqueue("Element1");
loConcurrentQueue.Enqueue("Element2");

var loList = loConcurrentQueue.DrainTo();
```

Comment: This does not give you a similar guarantee as drainTo does. Which is that you get all elements out atomically, meaning that publishers are blocked from adding more elements until the draining has stopped. Without that guarantee you risk that there's an infinite loop happening where you never get to the end of the queue because of busy publishing.